# Let $B\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ with positive entries. Prove that for $r>\rho(B)$ (spectral radius) then...

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

the matrix $A=rI-B$ is nonsingular and $A^{-1}$ has nonnegative entries.

It's pretty easy to prove that $A$ is nonsingular since 
$$r\notin\text{spec}(B)\iff \det(rI-B)=\det(A)\neq 0.$$ But how do I go about showing that the entries of $A^{-1}$ are nonnegative? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $B$ has positive entries by assumption. Also, note that $r>\rho(B)\geq0$. Now we wish to show that $A^{-1}$ has non-negative entries, where $A=rI-B$. Now,

\begin{align*}
A^{-1} &= (rI-B)^{-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{r}\left(I-\frac{1}{r}B\right)^{-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{r} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{r}B\right)^k
\end{align*}
We have that $\frac{1}{r^k}>0$ for all $k$, and $B$ has entries that are all positive so $B^k$ has all positive entries for all $k$ as well. Then, the sum of positive entries will of course remain positive. Hence, $A^{-1}$ has all non-negative entries.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Write $A^{-1}$ using an infinite series

---

**Second Hint:** We have

$$
(I - M)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty M^k
$$
whenever the sum on the right converges (where we define $M^0 = I$ by convention).  If $M$ has positive entries, then so does $M^k$ for $k \geq 1$.

Comment: Uh... how? Is there not a simpler way?

Comment: Recall that $1/(1-x) = 1+x+x^2 +\cdots$ for $|x| < 1$.

Comment: $1/(1-A)$ where is a matrix doesn't make sense

Comment: @Jeff but $(I - A)^{-1}$ does

Comment: So $(I-A)^{-1}=I+A+A^2+\cdots = I+(rI-B)+(r^2I-2rB+B^2)+\cdots$... I don't see how this helps.

Comment: In fact we don't know that $rI - B$ is a positive matrix, so I agree that your observation doesn't help.  How about $(rI - B) = r(I - \frac 1r B)$, though?

Comment: The same matrix? Written differently? I would say we still don't know.

Comment: @Jeff I would say that the formula makes it clear that $(I - \frac 1r B)^{-1}$ will be a positive matrix.  Using this, we can argue that $r(I - \frac 1r B)$ will also have a positive inverse.